# A Counterexample to the HIrsch Conjecture

Tags: convex-polytopes

Recently Francisco Santos has announced that he has a counterexample to the Hirsch conjecture. The last I heard it was circulating among several people and there would be a public version of it available soon. I am curious how close it is to release. Also has there been any progress in the attempt to find the vertices of the counterexample. The last I heard to find the vertices a series of steps had to be done and each step increased the complexity of the problem by a geometric factor making it difficult to complete the computation.

Comment: There is some information at Gil Kalai's blog, http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/francisco-santos-disproves-the-hirsch-conjecture/

Comment: Santos has a comment on Gil's blog saying that May 24 was an approximate deadline for release. looks like it's overdue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public version is now out. It is available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2814)